# How to control the sending rate of the server in short time (e.g., 1s)

Tags: sockets, networking, bandwidth

I want to control the data sending rate of the server under a very short time (1s), such as changing the sending rate each 100ms and make 10 times this adjustment in 1s. Is there a way to do this fine control?

Comment: For what purpose? TCP will work as hard as it can against this.

Comment: @user207421 I want to make a fine-grained control of the system, such as allocating bandwidth resources to different flows, and these flows won't last long (about 1s average).

Comment: TCP already does a far better job of bandwidth allocation than you could ever do from userspace, and as I said above it will actively conspire against your attempt.

Comment: @user207421 But TCP won't care about the user experience, so we still have some chance to optimize and do some allocation and scheduling, am I right?

Comment: @user207421 I think I can send packets in a `while` loop and use the `sleep` method to adjust the feed rate on the server, when I want to send with a higher rate I can sleep a shorter time and continue to feed the send buffer by `send`, is that ok?

Comment: PTAL: [network emulator](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem), this is not applicable to the single process but to the whole system

Comment: Sure you can limit the amount by creating your own buffer and calc the desired average data volume to send/recv. As you mentioned - yes you can do it in a while loop and use sleep()  as an approach.